# How to write a header when creating a new file, but omit it when just appending?

Tags: python

I am using this command line to create a file in append mode, with the aim of just appending new lines when launching the script again. But, how can I write the header when creating the file?

This is my command:

```
out_summary_file=os.environ["output_file"]

for sampleId in sampleList:
    pathology = pathology(sampleId)
    insulin_rate = insulin_rate(sampleId, threshold)
    with open(out_summary_file, 'a') as outFile:
        outFile.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(sampleId, pathology, insulin_rate))
```

My objective is to get a file with a different row for each sampleId, composed by 3 columns:

```
sampleId    pathology    insulin_rate

sampleA     colorrectal  high
sampleB     lung         normal
.           .            .
```

Depending on the new data, I may be interested to append the information to a preexisting output file or to create a new one. So, how can I automatically write a header when creating a new file, while just appending when using a preexisting file?

Comment: After opening, test the file position with `outFile.tell()`. If it is 0, write the header.

Comment: That has worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the file exists first. If it does, just append. If it doesn't, create it with a header.

```
import os

if os.path.isfile(filename):
    # file exists, just append
else:
    # file doesn't exist, create with header
```